# Node.js для управления windows доменом

Tags: javascript, node.js, active-directory, exchange

Делаем web приложение для управления доменом windows - создание учетных записей в Active directory, Exchange, управления группами AD и пр.
Преследую две цели:

1. Сделать само приложение, для упрощения создания учеток во всех используемых системах (домен, почта, vpn, erp)
2. Изучить Javascript/Node.js на практике.

Под инфраструктуру MS наверное правильней писать на C#, но это конфликтует с п.2

Возможно ли использовать JS для этих целей? Какие модули использовать? Что по теме почитать?

Comment: Ilya здравствуй. Преследую ту же цель, что и вы. Хотел посмотреть на ваши наработки в этом вопросе, а так же узнать, на каком инструменте для решения данной задачи вы остановились! Заранее спасибо большое.

Comment: Привет, этот проект не вышел за рамки идеи и общих размышлений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работа с доменом из nodejs более чем реальна.
буквально вчера была такая задача решилась с помощью библиотеки
[node-activedirectory](https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory)

javascript это всего лишь язык программирования и на нём можно реализовать практически всё что угодно как и других языках. просто что-то будет сделать проще, а что-то сложнее.

Для nodejs есть окромное количество библиотек [npmjs.com](https://www.npmjs.com/).

Comment: Видел этот модуль, но насколько я понял он и еще один ldapjs предназначены для аутенификации и чтения из AD.

Comment: согласен в модуле node-activedirectory нет встроенных методов  по CRUD сразу не обратил внимание т.к. было не нужно и как Вы, правильно, заметили существует модуль ldapjs  и документации как раз есть описание как можно добавлять [ldapjs client](http://ldapjs.org/client.html). Попроборвал пользователь добавился :-)